# Adding dataframe columns together, separated by columns considering NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, join

How could NaN values be completely ommitted from the new column in order to avoid consecutive commas?

```
df['newcolumn'] = df.apply(''.join, axis=1)
```

One approach would probably be using a conditional lambda

```
df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)) if(np.isnan(x.astype(str))) else '', axis = 1)
```

But this returns an error message:

> TypeError: ("ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the
>   inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
>   the casting rule ''safe''", 'occurred at index 0')

**Edit:**
Both your answers work. In order to obtain the answer, what critera would I use to determine which one to code? Performance considerations?

Comment: if you look for performance consideration, check my EDIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `stack` , since it will remove the `NaN` by default

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
Out[552]: 
0    a,t,y
1      a,t
2    a,u,y
3    a,u,n
4      a,u
5    b,t,y
dtype: object
```

---

Data input

---

```
df
Out[553]: 
  Mary John David
0    a    t     y
1    a    t   NaN
2    a    u     y
3    a    u     n
4    a    u   NaN
5    b    t     y
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dropna` in your `apply` such as:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis = 1)
```

With @Wen input for df, if you compare for small df, this one is slightly faster

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()),1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop
%timeit df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 ms per loop
```

but for bigger dataframe, @Wen answer is way faster

```
df_long = pd.concat([df]*1000)
%timeit df_long.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()),1)
1 loop, best of 3: 850 ms per loop
%timeit df_long.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.1 ms per loop
```